# jqgrid navigation bar not working (of child table)

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, jqgrid, pagination

I am developing a web application using JSP & Servlet (IDE: Eclipse, Database: Oracle10).

I am using `jqGrid` to display records in tabular format.
I have designed a `header` and `Details` table using `jqGrid`, in which if we click on any row of the `Header` table then the rows from `Details` table will be changed accordingly. I have Taken separate `jqGrid` for `Header` and `Details` Table.

Now if I click on the row of `Header` Table then it is showing the related data in the `jqGrid` of `Details` table

But the problem is that `Navigation Bar` of `Header` is working fine, but `Navigation Bar` of `Details` Table is not working. If I click on Next page button then also it is showing me the same result again.

[Note: Add, Edit and Delete buttons of both are working fine, only Navigation of records for `Details` table is not working]

**`Header`:**

```
jQuery("#list10").jqGrid({
            url:'ProtocolJGridServ?q=2&action=protocol',
            datatype: "xml",
            height: 250,
            colNames:['Sr. No.','PROTOCOL_ID','DESCRIPTION','PURPOSE','PROTOCOL_TYPE','TARGET','START_DATE','END_DATE','TRIGGER_NAME'],
            colModel:[{name:'srNo',index:'srNo', width:35,sortable:true},
                      {name:'PROTOCOL_ID',index:'PROTOCOL_ID', width:100,sortable:true,editable:true},
                      {name:'DESCRIPTION',index:'DESCRIPTION', width:200,sortable:false,editable:true},
                      {name:'PURPOSE',index:'PURPOSE', width:100,sortable:false,editable:true},
                      ],
            rowNum:5,
            rowList:[3,5,10],
            pager: '#pager10',
            sortname: 'srNO',

            loadonce:true,

            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: "desc",
            multiselect: false,
            editurl: "ProtocolJGridServ?action=protocolEdit",
            caption: "Protocol",
            onSelectRow: function(ids,status)
            {
                if(status==true)
                {
                    if(ids)
                    {
                        var cm = $('#list10').jqGrid('getColProp',"PROTOCOL_ID");  cm.editable=false;
                        var ret = jQuery("#list10").jqGrid('getRowData',ids);
                        protID = ret.PROTOCOL_ID;

                        jQuery("#list10").jqGrid('setGridParam', {editurl:'ProtocolJGridServ?action=protocolEdit&protID='+protID});
                        jQuery('#list10').jqGrid('restoreRow',lastsel);
                        jQuery('#list10').jqGrid('editRow',ids,true);
                        lastsel=ids;
                        cm = $('#list10').jqGrid('getColProp',"PROTOCOL_ID");  cm.editable=true;
                    }
                if(ids!=null)
                    {
                        var PROTOCOL_ID = $('#list10').getCell(ids, 'PROTOCOL_ID');
                        //for CRM_PROTOCOL_STAGES
                        jQuery("#list10_d2").jqGrid('setGridParam',{url:"ProtocolJGridServChildStages?action=protStages&q=1&protID="+PROTOCOL_ID,page:1});
                        jQuery("#list10_d2").jqGrid('setCaption',"CRM_PROT_STAGES: "+ids)
                        .trigger('reloadGrid');
                    }
                }
                else //status = false = row de-selected 
                {
                    if(ids)
                    {
                        jQuery('#list10').jqGrid('restoreRow',lastsel);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

**`Details`:**

```
jQuery("#list10_d2").jqGrid({
            height: "100%",
            url:'ProtocolJGridServChildStages?q=2&action=protStages',
            datatype: "xml",
             colNames:['Sr. No.','PROTOCOL_ID',  'STAGE_ID',  'DESCRIPTION'],
             colModel:[{name:'srNo',index:'srNo', width:50,sortable:true},
                       {name:'PROTOCOL_ID',index:'PROTOCOL_ID', width:100,sortable:false,editable:true,hidden:true},
                       {name:'STAGE_ID',index:'STAGE_ID', width:100,sortable:false,editable:true},
                       {name:'DESCRIPTION',index:'DESCRIPTION', width:150,sortable:false,editable:true}
                       ],
            rowNum:2,
            rowList:[2,4,10],

            //paging: true,
        //loadonce:true,
            pager: '#pager10_d2',
            sortname: 'PROTOCOL_ID',
                //viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: "asc",
            multiselect: true,
            editurl: "ProtocolJGridServChildStages?action=protocolStageEdit",
            caption:"CRM_PROT_STAGES",
            afterInsertRow: function(ids) 
            {
                var ret = jQuery("#list10_d2").jqGrid('getRowData',ids);
                protID = ret.PROTOCOL_ID;
            },
            onSelectRow: function(ids,status)
            {
                if(status==true)
                {
                    if(ids)
                    {
                        var cm = $('#list10_d2').jqGrid('getColProp',"PROTOCOL_ID");  cm.editable=false; var cm2 = $('#list10_d2').jqGrid('getColProp',"STAGE_ID");  cm2.editable=false;
                        var ret = jQuery("#list10_d2").jqGrid('getRowData',ids);
                        protID = ret.PROTOCOL_ID;
                        stageID = ret.STAGE_ID;

                        jQuery("#list10_d2").jqGrid('setGridParam',{editurl:'ProtocolJGridServChildStages?action=protocolStageEdit&protID='+protID+'&stageID='+stageID});
                        jQuery('#list10_d2').jqGrid('restoreRow',lastsel);
                        jQuery('#list10_d2').jqGrid('editRow',ids,true);
                        lastsel=ids;
                        var cm = $('#list10_d2').jqGrid('getColProp',"PROTOCOL_ID");  cm.editable=true; var cm2 = $('#list10_d2').jqGrid('getColProp',"STAGE_ID");  cm2.editable=true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if(ids)
                    {
                        jQuery('#list10_d2').jqGrid('restoreRow',lastsel);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

**Update 1: ---  Servlet Code:**

```
int page = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("page")); // get the requested page
            int limit = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("rows")); // get how many rows we want to have into the grid
            String sidx = request.getParameter("sidx"); // get index row - i.e. user click to sort
            String sord = request.getParameter("sord"); // get the direction
            int start = (limit* page) - limit;              
            String rows = request.getParameter("rows");
            String param = request.getParameter("protID");

            //get the data
            String query = "select * from CRM_PROT_STAGES where PROTOCOL_ID ='"+param+"'";

            //String query = "select * from( select * from CRM_PROT_STAGES  where  PROTOCOL_ID = '"+param +"' order by PROTOCOL_ID desc) where  ROWNUM <= "+limit;
            //String query = "select * from ( select a.*, ROWNUM rnum from ( select * from CRM_PROT_STAGES  where  PROTOCOL_ID = '"+param +"' ) a where ROWNUM <= "+ limit +")where rnum  >="+start;

            data = select.getData(query);   //getData() return 2D array of data
            columnNames = select.getColumnNames();   //getColumnNames() returns array of column names

            int totalCount = data.length;
            int totalPages = 0;

            if (totalCount > 0) 
            {
                if (totalCount % Integer.parseInt(rows) == 0) 
                {
                    totalPages = totalCount / Integer.parseInt(rows);
                } 
                else
                {
                    totalPages = (totalCount / Integer.parseInt(rows)) + 1;
                }
            } 
            else 
            {
                totalPages = 0;
            }
            out.print("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>\n");
            out.print("<rows>");
            out.print("<page>" + request.getParameter("page") + "</page>");
            out.print("<total>" + totalPages + "</total>");
            out.print("<records>" + totalCount + "</records>");
            int srNo = 1;

            limit = limit+start;
            //for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++)
            if(totalCount>0)
                for(int i=start;i<limit;i++)
                {
                    if(i<data.length)
                    {
                        out.print("<row id='" + i + "'>");
                        out.print("<cell>" + srNo + "</cell>");
                        for(int a=0;a<columnNames.length;a++)
                        {
                            out.print("<cell>"+ data[i][a] +"</cell>");
                        }
                    out.print("</row>");
                    srNo++;
                    }
                }
                out.print("</rows>");
                data=null;
                columnNames=null;
        }
```

Let me know if there is anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that the reason on the problem is the following: you use `loadonce:true` in the "Header" (Master) grid, but not in the "Details" grid. So the paging of "Header" is implemented on the *client side* by jqGrid and one needs implement *server side paging* in URL code of `ProtocolJGridServChildStages` fof successful paging on "Details" grid.

So I suggest that you just add `loadonce:true` option for "Details" grid.

Comment: I have also tried using `loadonce:true` for `Details` table, but if I use it then the `Details` table doesn't show any records. Then I implemented `server side paging` for `Details` table, and it is working fine. I have Updated code in my question. But now problem is that every time user clicks on navigation button query is submitted to the server and then the result given to the client. But I think this is not the best way to do it, so let me know if you find any issue which is stopping client side paging of `Details` table.

Comment: +1 for `server side paging` because it solved my problem temporarily

Comment: @Bhushan: I don't see that you use paging in SQL query. You can use pseudocolumn `ROWNUM` to limit query results for example. The choice between server side and client side paging can depend on the number of rows displayed typically in Detailed grid. Moreover you should verify whether the table `CRM_PROT_STAGES` has index on `PROTOCOL_ID` or *compost indexes* with on two fields `PROTOCOL_ID` and the second column by which you allow to sort the grid.

Comment: @Bhushan: I can't imagine which error you made so that including `loadonce:true` follows no rows to display. Morover I don't understand what you mean under "now problem is that every time user clicks on navigation button query is submitted to the server". If you mean clicks on pagination buttons, then it's *exactly what server side paging should do*. If you have good organized tables with indexes in database and if you execute correct SQL statements on the server then reaction of the grid will be almost immediate for the user.